# When angry we shout "F***!", but what do 日本人 shout?

Tags: word-choice, culture

I have to ask, when you kick a Japanese boy in the nuts or whatever, ignoring the obvious sounds a human makes when entering into such a state, what bits of language will they impulsively shout in their anger.

I ask this as in English we have a beautiful array of anglo saxon gems to choose from, but in Japanese what is the equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am too soft-spoken a person to be familiar with cuss words, but here are some examples in no particular order.

- 「畜生{ちくしょう}」
- 「くそっ」
- 「くそったれ」
- 「てめえ」
- 「てめえ、この野郎{やろう}」
- 「この野郎」
- 「くそ野郎」
- 「ボケ」
- 「死{し}ね」
- 「死{し}にやがれ」
- 「くたばれ」
- 「このくそガキ」
- 「くそ食{く}らえ」
- 「ざけんな」
- 「ざけんな、ボケっ」
- 「ざけんじゃねえ」
- etc.

Around Nagoya, we have 「たあけ」, which comes from the old, elegant word 「戯{たわ}け」.

Stop me now or I'll be typing words/phrases I shouldn't be in public.

Note: 「ざけんな」 is the slangy pronunciation of 「ふざけるな」.

Comment: Not too sure about expletive words, but この野郎 and くそ野郎 are little bit harsher than 馬鹿野郎, sometimes 己 「おのれ」 may used to tell "you" with insulting purpose and high tone.

Comment: Note that apart from the first two, all the rest imply that you are angry with _someone in earshot._ (The first two are neutral in that they don't have to be about a specific person.)

Comment: For someone who is "too soft-spoken" that is quite a list. Also of note is that instead of cursing, sometimes just 痛い！ is used.

Answer (score 2):

The best equivalent to F*** would probably be "kuso".(which means s***).
But if you kick someone down there they probably will say "konoyaro" or "onore" to you.(which can be interpreted as "you son of a *****").

Comment: Do people actually say おのれ? I always had the impression it was a bit dated and nobody would actually say it.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I think the most usual thing for equivalent use is ふざける and its derivatives. But this really depends on what one takes people to mean with f***

Comment: @Kurausukun well, konoyaro is probably used way more often, but to be honest I have never heard anyone say either of those 2 in my whole life.... These kinds of situations are very rare, so it is hard to confirm.